# Two different color in background and Inside center box is container in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In this picture  - sample outline

[image]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Try using background: linear-gradient

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this using a mix of `border-image` and `linear-gradient` like this:

```css
.content {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  
  border-width: 40px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient( blue 40%, red 30%) 1 round;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">Content</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

This question could be clarified but if I'm right you want the two to have different colors 
You need to see the class before them and in css edit the class like

```
 .container{
background-color: red !important;
}
```

Of this for each element especially when using bootstrap remember to put !important
Behind anything that would override the normal  setup